# What is interferring with this custom insets inside a UIButton?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, uikit

I was playing around with the code from [John Sundell's *Applying rounded corners to a UIKit or SwiftUI view*](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/rounded-corners-uikit-swiftui/) in a Playground when I noticed this surprising behavior, a zero edge insets setting does lead to some y-axis padding inside the UIButton whereas adding strictly positive x-axis insets does remove the y-axis padding. Any idea what explains this behavior?

[image: 0-inset leads to y-axis padding]

[image: Adding some x-axis insets cancels the y-axis padding]

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's docs for [UIButton .contentEdgeInsets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624036-contentedgeinsets):

> ... The default value is zero.
>
> The button uses this property to determine intrinsicContentSize and sizeThatFits(_:).

While it's not clear, if the `.contentEdgeInsets` are at their default, UIKit adds default Top and Bottom "padding".

If any of the values are *not* at the default of Zero, UIKit assumes you have set the values exactly as you want them.